# Extract string between strings

Tags: html, plaintext

I am trying to extract mailing addresses contained within entries on a website (and export to CSV).  The page is coded such that over 400 address-containing entries are grouped into a single web element, and the data cannot be scraped automatically. The addresses appear between two identical strings for every single entry.

E.g.

"4pm to 9pm, **12345 Main St, Seattle, WA,** Bring friends!"

Comment: 1. What are those strings ('The addresses appear between two identical strings for every single entry')
2. have you already tried something?

Comment: 1. Example? 2. What have been done (code)? 3. What the problem you met?

Comment: Yes, I have spent a couple hours in RegEx trying to derive an expression that will do this--no dice.  I have extremely limited knowledge of HTML, RegEx, and Java, though I spent quite a bit of time trying to get what I needed this morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Regular Expressions to achieve that. You didnt provided any details about the program language you will use to do that, so i will cover only the regular expression part (and then you can do some research of how to do it with your preferred language - almost all languages provide great support of Regular Expressions).

Lets take the string

> "4pm to 9pm, **12345 Main St, Seattle, WA**, Bring friends!"

Using regular expressions to extract the portion of the string you want:

```
/^4pm to 9pm, ([A-Za-z0-9, ]+), Bring friends\!$/
```

It can be tweak to attend to your needs (you only provide 1 sample of the string, other samples can affect the results). Try it in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com)

UPDATE:

based on the comment, you could use a regular expression like:

```
/pm\n([A-Za-z0-9, ]+)\nInstructors/
```

You should revise the character classes (the characters that can appear in the address). I've tested in regex101.com and it worked for the example you provided in the comments.

Comment: I tried transposing into the actual strings, but it didn't work.  Here's a snip of one of the actual entries:

"10/12/2017 Thursday 4pm to 9pm\nEagle Home Mortgage, 1110 College St SE Ste C Lacey\nInstructors: Kirk D., Lacey\nand Sarah, Weichert Realtor - Olympia \nPlease note: For reservations call or email homebuyerclasswa@. Please bring a sack lunch. Reservations required. Seating limited. Refreshments provided."

**All of the addresses are between "pm\n" and "\nInstructors"**

Comment: Great, that got it.  Thank you for helping a noob. :)

Comment: One last thing: can the expression be tweaked to discard the "pm\n" and "\nInstructors"?  Right now, it's extracting the addresses and the adjacent strings.

Comment: It depends on the language and the functions you're using to capture the portion of the string. For example, the php's function preg_match, has a 3rd parameter called $matches that returns to you all the matche expression and the parentised string. You want only the parentised string... do some search on how to get it.

Comment: Thanks again.  I was able to use the **(?= look ahead/behind features to grab the data.  Much appreciated.